# Realistic Landmass Formation on Torus-Shaped Planet

Tags: science-based, worldbuilding-process, map-making

Having recently discovered that [torus-shaped planets can actually form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJvbO_rR07g), I've started to consider using that design as a setting for a map(no real purpose in mind, just map making for the sake of it). How would I realistically simulate the formation of landmasses?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Lysander Cox! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: As you, I'm curious about this, I suspect there are many in the same doughnut ship,  but haven't thought of a way to ask a question about it yet, please try the sandbox as Gryphon sais, we're with you.

Comment: Sorry, I'd just like to clarify what the issue with the question is.

Comment: @Lysander Cox Which "the question" ? You have three distinct questions. The realistic simulation one, for a video game or "simulate" in what sense? Tectonic plate rules - would they apply the same as spherica planets. Not my field, basically noone's field, it's speculative and may come down to a matterof opinion - which is off topic.Would the necessary... etc. How would anyone know? We would need to speculate again making this opinion based. Then you need to specify what would constitute a "good" answer. The Sandbox can help you refine all this.

Comment: Hi Lysander - that's a very interesting concept for a question. Joining the other recommendations for using the sandbox. Two suggestions for starters: 1. SE sites work with a "One Question / One Answer" model. Consider splitting this question to several linked questions (e.g. "How will tectonics change for a toroid planet?", "Can a toroid planet survive impacts strong enough to catalyze plate division?", "Mapmaking: How to realistically simulate landmass formation for a toroid planet?") - If you care about a single question in particular, try making it more obvious to readers.

Comment: (cont.) 2. After narrowing the post to a single question, consider adding more details and limitations - this will help focus the answers, making them more useful and easier to judge. We all want the best answers to show on top. It's easier to judge an answer to "Can a toroid planet survive impacts strong enough to catalyze plate division?" if we also know that we are discussing e.g. a planet with Earth-like conditions (surface gravity, atmosphere, composition) or an ice moon with the mass of Titan (etc. etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Artifexian has a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1J4iIBKJHLA) on this subject on YouTube! In it he explains that due to the inner radius being smaller than the outer, continental plates moving inward will need to shrink and thus experience folding, creating mountains. Plates moving outward will have to grow and thus are torn apart. The surface gravity on the 'equators' is also lower than at the poles (slightly inside of the poles it is at a maximum) which makes for very large mountains.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I'm afraid link-only answers aren't allowed here, as links aren't guaranteed to always work. You should edit the relevant points from the video into your answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy Makes a good point.  Please edit the relevant content into the question or it will likely get deleted.  You should also check out the [tour] and [help] to get an idea of how the site works.  Welcome to world building.

Comment: Until the pending edit goes through, you can watch the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1J4iIBKJHLA